# spark long delay before submitting jobs to the executors

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using spark-Cassandra driver through spark-sql  to query my Cassandra cluster. Each Cassandra node has a spark worker (co-located).

Problem: There is a long delay before submitting tasks to the executor (based on time stamps on web UI and also driver logs). The query is a simple select which specifies all cassandra partition keys and contains two stages and two tasks. Previously, the query took 300ms on another server with colocated driver and master.

But i have to move my application and spark master to another server (same as before but just on another physical server) and now the query took 40 seconds. Although task duration is about 7 seconds, Job took 40 seconds, i can not figure out what the extra delay is for?

I've also checked spark with a job with no connection to Cassandra, and it took 200ms, so i thought that its more related to spark-cassandra than to spark itself.

Here is spark logs during execution of job:

```
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:07.067 [qtp1151421920-470] SparkSqlParser 54 - Parsing command: select * from ...
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:07.276 [qtp1151421920-470] CassandraSourceRelation 35 - Input Predicates: ...
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:07.279 [qtp1151421920-470] ClockFactory 52 - Using native clock to generate timestamps.
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:07.439 [qtp1151421920-470] Cluster 1543 - New Cassandra host /192.168.1.201:9042 added
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:07.440 [qtp1151421920-470] Cluster 1543 - New Cassandra host /192.168.1.202:9042 added
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:07.440 [qtp1151421920-470] Cluster 1543 - New Cassandra host /192.168.1.203:9042 added
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:07.440 [qtp1151421920-470] Cluster 1543 - New Cassandra host /192.168.1.204:9042 added
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:07.446 [qtp1151421920-470] CassandraConnector 35 - Connected to Cassandra cluster: Digger Cluster
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:07.526 [qtp1151421920-470] CassandraSourceRelation 35 - Input Predicates: ...
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:07.848 [qtp1151421920-470] CodeGenerator 54 - Code generated in 120.31952 ms
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:08.264 [qtp1151421920-470] CodeGenerator 54 - Code generated in 15.084165 ms
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:08.289 [qtp1151421920-470] CodeGenerator 54 - Code generated in 17.893182 ms
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:08.379 [qtp1151421920-470] SparkContext 54 - Starting job: collectAsList at MyClass.java:5
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:08.394 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - Registering RDD 12 (toJSON at MyClass.java.java:5)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:08.397 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - Got job 0 (collectAsList at MyClass.java.java:5) with 1 output partitions
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:08.398 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - Final stage: ResultStage 1 (collectAsList at MyClass.java.java:5)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:08.398 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:08.400 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - Missing parents: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:08.405 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - Submitting ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[12] at toJSON at MyClass.java.java:5), which has no missing parents
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:15.703 [pool-44-thread-1] CassandraConnector 35 - Disconnected from Cassandra cluster: Digger Cluster
-----------------long delay here
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:43.547 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] MemoryStore 54 - Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 20.6 KB, free 17.8 GB)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:43.579 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] MemoryStore 54 - Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 9.5 KB, free 17.8 GB)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:43.581 [dispatcher-event-loop-1] BlockManagerInfo 54 - Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.94:38311 (size: 9.5 KB, free: 17.8 GB)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:43.584 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] SparkContext 54 - Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:43.597 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - Submitting 1 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[12] at toJSON at MyClass.java.java:5) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:43.598 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] TaskSchedulerImpl 54 - Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:43.619 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] FairSchedulableBuilder 54 - Added task set TaskSet_0.0 tasks to pool rest
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:43.652 [dispatcher-event-loop-35] TaskSetManager 54 - Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 192.168.1.210, executor 11, partition 0, NODE_LOCAL, 6357 bytes)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:43.920 [dispatcher-event-loop-36] BlockManagerInfo 54 - Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.210:42612 (size: 9.5 KB, free: 912.3 MB)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.591 [task-result-getter-0] TaskSetManager 54 - Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 2963 ms on 192.168.1.210 (executor 11) (1/1)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.594 [task-result-getter-0] TaskSchedulerImpl 54 - Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool rest
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.601 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - ShuffleMapStage 0 (toJSON at MyClass.java.java:5) finished in 2.981 s
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.602 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - looking for newly runnable stages
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.603 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - running: Set()
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.603 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - waiting: Set(ResultStage 1)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.604 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - failed: Set()
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.608 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - Submitting ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[18] at collectAsList at MyClass.java.java:5), which has no missing parents
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.615 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] MemoryStore 54 - Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 20.8 KB, free 17.8 GB)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.618 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] MemoryStore 54 - Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 9.8 KB, free 17.8 GB)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.619 [dispatcher-event-loop-21] BlockManagerInfo 54 - Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.94:38311 (size: 9.8 KB, free: 17.8 GB)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.620 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] SparkContext 54 - Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.622 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[18] at collectAsList at MyClass.java.java:5) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.622 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] TaskSchedulerImpl 54 - Adding task set 1.0 with 1 tasks
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.622 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] FairSchedulableBuilder 54 - Added task set TaskSet_1.0 tasks to pool rest
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.627 [dispatcher-event-loop-25] TaskSetManager 54 - Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, 192.168.1.212, executor 9, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4730 bytes)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:46.851 [dispatcher-event-loop-9] BlockManagerInfo 54 - Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 192.168.1.212:43471 (size: 9.8 KB, free: 912.3 MB)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:47.257 [dispatcher-event-loop-38] MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint 54 - Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 192.168.1.212:46794
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:47.262 [map-output-dispatcher-0] MapOutputTrackerMaster 54 - Size of output statuses for shuffle 0 is 141 bytes
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:47.763 [task-result-getter-1] TaskSetManager 54 - Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) in 1140 ms on 192.168.1.212 (executor 9) (1/1)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:47.763 [task-result-getter-1] TaskSchedulerImpl 54 - Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool rest
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:47.765 [dag-scheduler-event-loop] DAGScheduler 54 - ResultStage 1 (collectAsList at MyClass.java.java:5) finished in 1.142 s
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 06:59:47.771 [qtp1151421920-470] DAGScheduler 54 - Job 0 finished: collectAsList at MyClass.java.java:5, took 39.391066 s

[INFO ] 2019-03-04 07:00:09.014 [Spark Context Cleaner] ContextCleaner 54 - Cleaned accumulator 4
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 07:00:09.015 [Spark Context Cleaner] ContextCleaner 54 - Cleaned accumulator 0
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 07:00:09.015 [Spark Context Cleaner] ContextCleaner 54 - Cleaned accumulator 3
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 07:00:09.015 [Spark Context Cleaner] ContextCleaner 54 - Cleaned accumulator 1
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 07:00:09.028 [dispatcher-event-loop-10] BlockManagerInfo 54 - Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on 192.168.1.94:38311 in memory (size: 9.8 KB, free: 17.8 GB)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 07:00:09.045 [dispatcher-event-loop-0] BlockManagerInfo 54 - Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on 192.168.1.212:43471 in memory (size: 9.8 KB, free: 912.3 MB)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 07:00:09.063 [Spark Context Cleaner] ContextCleaner 54 - Cleaned shuffle 0
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 07:00:09.065 [dispatcher-event-loop-16] BlockManagerInfo 54 - Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on 192.168.1.94:38311 in memory (size: 9.5 KB, free: 17.8 GB)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 07:00:09.071 [dispatcher-event-loop-37] BlockManagerInfo 54 - Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on 192.168.1.210:42612 in memory (size: 9.5 KB, free: 912.3 MB)
[INFO ] 2019-03-04 07:00:09.074 [Spark Context Cleaner] ContextCleaner 54 - Cleaned accumulator 2
```

Also attached screenshots to spark web ui for the job and its tasks.Logs and images are not for the same job.

P.S: Is spark-cassandra connectors creates a new session each time i run a query (i see connect-disconnect to cassandra cluster everytime)? i run many queries in parallel, isn't that going to be much slower than pure-cassandra?

[spark job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnf7Y.png)
[image: spark job's tasks]

Comment: what versions of connector, spark and cassandra?

Comment: cassandra: 3.11.2, spark: 2.2.1, connector_2.11 2.0.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking with jvisualvm, Executors had no activity during the time gap, but the driver (my application) had a thread called "dag-scheduler..." running only at the time gap. The thread dump said that it stuck on InetAddress.getHostName().

Then in debug mode, i put a breakpoint there and find out that it's trying to reverse lookup (ip to hostname) for all of my cassandra-cluster, **so just added all "IP  HOSTNAME"s of my cassandra cluster to the end of /etc/hosts and problem solved!**